# Laravel 5.8 - How-to UPDATE Table Inside Loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have two tables: "**users**" and "**records**". The table "**records**" I need to apply (update) col "fk_user" to it getting from "**users**".

Not a big deal until now, correct? Should it be this way...

What I am doing is:

1. Query Users (with just 5 ones at this moment) Table using Query Builder (DB) and do something like : `$users->each(function($i) use ($query)){`
2. Inside ".each" loop, I just call:

> $users->each(function($i) use ($query){
>
> $query->update(['fk_user' => $i->id, 'status' => 1, 'updated_at' =
>   \Carbon\Carbon::now()]);

3. So, **the result should be 150 updates** in a block of 30 matches for each user!
4. But when I query the table there is 300 updates in place.
5. Why?

And I really can´t understand why!

This is exactly the way doing things here:

```
$query = DB::table('records as bp')
->whereRaw('bp.control = '.$control.' AND bp.status = 0')
->limit(30);

$users = Users::all();
$users->each(function($i) use ($query){
        $query->update(['fk_user' => $i->id, 'status' => 1, 'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
});
```

**Important : I already tried to declare $query inside "each" and the result was the same!**

Thanks for any support here.

Comment: `DB::table('records_table')->limit(30)->update(['fk_user' => $i->id]);` Won't that just update the same 30 records in every loop? Are you missing an `offset()`? Can you provide the complete (or at lease the most relevant) code you're using? It's a lot harder to debug if we have to piece things together

Comment: @TimLewis No. Because of "->limit(30)" and the "status".

Comment: Gotcha, although `->whereRaw('status'= 0)` looks like a syntax error. `->where("status", "=", 0)` should suffice.

Comment: @TimLewis As you asked me for, take a look above. Its not a syntax error, I guarantee, the routine runs perfectly only with that inconvenient. And by the way, remember, I am using "whereRaw" - Query Builder, not eloquent at this time.

Comment: `->where()` works perfectly fine on `DB::table()`, but regardless, if you want to use `whereRaw()`, then go ahead. All I'm saying is that this `->whereRaw('status'= 0)` is wrong. Your actual code is `->whereRaw('bp.control = '.$control.' AND bp.status = 0')`, is perfectly fine, but that's two different snippets... Next time, just post your actual code so this confusion doesn't happen :)

Comment: @TimLewis about snippets, you are right and sorry for that.

Comment: No worries :) I can see your code is free of syntax errors now, so that's good. However, I don't see how that issue would be happening. Are you familiar with the Query Log? https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging for reference. You can enable that and see all queries being executed; might shed some light on your case.

Comment: @TimLewis - Well done. I am using barryvdh/laravel-debugbar. In Queries, I see exactly what it is expected to be, 6 queries, 1 - For 'users' and 5 - for 'records'. I think, probably, there must be something with cache...at the final end, it exec once again.